# How do I solve a Knapsack Problem with minimizing value?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am given a file of meals containing their calories and fat value information in that form -->

330 350 100 230 //This is Calories
30 27 10 10 //This is fat

The user can also input a "wanted calories" amount.

My task is to use dynamic programming in order to create an algorithm that outputs the amount of calories and a list of the meals used to reach it. Each meal can only be used once, the fat needs to be minimized, and my output of calories needs to be as close as possible to the "wanted calories" amount that I got as input...

I figured that this is quite similar to the knapsack problem with my "wanted calories" being the capacity of my bag, the calories being the weight of each item and the fat being the value of each item.

The problem as far as i can tell is that unlike the normal knapsack problem where the value needs to be maximized, in this case it needs to be minimized.

private int minimumFat(int wantedCalories, int[] calories, int[] fat) {

```
    int n = fat.length;

    int min_fat[][] = new int[n+1][wantedCalories+1];

    // Fill 0th Row with infinity
    for (int i=0; i <= wantedCalories; i++) {
        min_fat[0][i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    // Fill 0th Column with 0
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        min_fat[i][0] = 0;
    }

    // Check each weight one by one
    for (int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ")");
        for (int j=1; j<=wantedCalories; j++) {
            if (calories[i-1] > j) {
                min_fat[i][j] = min_fat[i-1][j];
            } else {
                min_fat[i][j] = Math.min(min_fat[i-1][j], min_fat[i][j-calories[i-1]] + fat[i-1]);
            }
            System.out.print(min_fat[i-1][j-1] + " ");
        }
    }

    return min_fat[n][wantedCalories];
}
```

When running the above code my results are negative which as far as I can tell happens because Integer.MAX_VALUE overflows. I am not sure how I am supposed to continue from here since no matter what I put inside the Math.min it will always favor min_fat[i-1][j]. I expected the output to be the amount of fat used by the meal plan so that I could then trace back and find the total amount of calories used as well as the items that made the meal plan but that's clearly not what happened.

Comment: Is there anything specific about which objective should be prioritized ? Minimize `|calories_expected - calories_of_meal|`, minimize `amount of fat`, or maybe you have to be in some threshold for calories for a meal to be acceptable .... if there is no such thing, then I'd say that it seems like a multicriteria optimization problem to me. The result of multicriteria problems are usually pareto sets, you can have a look at what [pareto efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) is.

Comment: Well I need to output a meal plan that has a total value of calories that is close to the wanted_calories value that I am given by the user and my amount of fat for that meal plan needs to be minimized.

Comment: "that is close to the wanted_calories value" - something is wrong with this requirement. it is supposed to be "that is at least wanted_calories value" if you're talking about minimization

Comment: you can easily convert minimization into maximization by negating the objective function and constraints. say you got obj.func like a1x1+...+anxn -> min and constraint like w1x1+...+wnxn >= C. this is equivalent to maximization problem with obj.func -a1x1-...-anxn -> max and constraint -w1x1-...-wnxn <= -C

Comment: Yeah I also figured there's something wrong with this considering I couldn't find anything that has this exact requirement. The assignment clearly says however that we need to minimize the fat and that the calories need to either be equal or as close as possible to the wanted_calories number without exceeding it. I am starting to think that this is either not a knapsack problem in which case I'll have to search for alternatives or that the assignment has typos in it in which case I'll need to send an e-mail....

Comment: if the calories should not exceed a specified value, you pick no meal at all and there's going to be 0 fat which is the smallest possible value : )

Comment: Yeah that would be an option actually but in the case that the wanted_calories are close to my output calories i should still output that meal. so if i have 200 as my output while my wanted calories are 360 then i should still output 200 with the meals used to make it up. The problem really is that i need to minimize the fat while also doing the above and that is what has been driving me crazy for the past couple of hours ahah xD